# ERROR in Cannot read property 'push' of undefined ngx-toastr

Tags: angular, typescript

In my application I am trying to integrate [Toastr](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjazzq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

as part of that I have intigrated the package.json and angular.json.
upto here application worked.but when I intigrated `app.module.ts`

**app.module.ts**

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      timeOut: 1000,
      positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right'
    })
  ],
export class AppModule { }
```

I am getting the following error.

```
@import must precede all other statements (besides @charset)

WARNING in Entry point 'ngx-toastr' contains deep imports into 'C:/Users/angular-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/core'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.

ERROR in Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by

`ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty`

Answer (score 0):

Decorate your imports with the @NgModule decorator:

```
import {ToastrModule} from 'ngx-toastr';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      timeOut: 1000,
      positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right'
    })
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

See https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules

Comment: Or, as the first line states, make sure all of your imports are at the top of the page